# Compare two different csv with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, csv

I'm trying to compare two csv which contains some events. Csv are big.csv and small.csv. Small csv contains events which are not listed in big.csv and I want to write them to output.csv.

Here is big.csv example:

```
1904945-3;444;UM2;139432;149252;6349;40101382;31.5.2019 19:20;31.5.2019 19:55;30,5;Maksussa;56,69;56,69;10;51,54;5,15;-1,28;0;51,02;49,74;10020494;19.6.2019
1904945-3;0;UM2;139530;149322;5393;40101316;31.5.2019 20:22;31.5.2019 20:50;4,85;Maksussa;42,67;42,67;10;38,79;3,88;-0,96;25;38,4;12,44;10071061;20.11.2019
1904945-3;476;UM2;139536;149309;2846;40101321;31.5.2019 20:31;31.5.2019 20:58;23,07;Maksussa;46,62;46,62;10;42,38;4,24;-1,05;25;41,96;15,91;10020494;19.6.2019
```

Here is small.csv example:

```
23;1992;31.5.2019 20:22;31.5.2019 20:50;2;22,73;2,27;17,67;25;4,85;00000;00000;00000;18,1;00000;00000;UM200190494530099530;00000;8,22
12;17;31.5.2019 20:32;31.5.2019 20:58;10;19,65;1,97;21,62;25;23,07;00000;00000;00000;6;00000;00000;UM200190494530129536;00000;8,22
12;17;31.5.2019 23:35;31.5.2019 23:36;10;19,65;1,97;21,62;25;23,07;00000;00000;00000;6;00000;00000;UM200190494530127777;00000;8,22
```

For finding the differences, I used three parameters: Start time, end time of events, and event's ID with substring (last 4 digits). This data in big.csv in columns 7, 8, and 3. Data in small.csv in columns 2, 3, and 16.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim big As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Ivan\Desktop\Test\isoraportti.csv").Skip(1).ToArray
    Dim small As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Ivan\Desktop\Test\kuittiraportti.csv").Skip(1).ToArray
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Label1.Visible = True
    For Each line1 In big
        Dim Fields1 = line1.Split(";"c)
        For Each line2 In small
            Dim Fields2 = line2.Split(";"c)
            Dim pv1 As Date = Fields1(7)
            Dim p1 As Date = Fields1(8)
            Dim pv2 As Date = Fields2(2)
            Dim p2 As Date = Fields2(3)
            Dim pvm1 = pv1.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")
            Dim pvm2 = pv2.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")
            Dim pvm3 = p1.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")
            Dim pvm4 = p2.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")
            Dim st2 As String = Fields2(16)
            Dim substr2 As String = st2.Substring(st2.Length - 4, 4)
            Dim st1 As String = Fields1(3)
            Dim substr1 As String = st1.Substring(st1.Length - 4, 4)
            If Not pvm2 = pvm1 And pvm3 = pvm4 And substr2 = substr1 Then
                Fields2(14) = substr2.ToString()
                sb.AppendLine(String.Join(";", Fields2))
            Else
                Label1.Text = "Ei löyty"
            End If
        Next
    Next

    IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\Ivan\Desktop\Test\output.csv", sb.ToString)
End Sub
```

But it doesn't work or works only partially. In small.csv example, the two last strings should be written to output.csv, but only first of them was written. I don't understand why the last string not written to output.csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matching check is wrong. As it is, you check that the start dates are not the same, but the end dates & event ID are the same. It should be:

```
If Not (pvm2 = pvm1 AndAlso pvm3 = pvm4 AndAlso substr2 = substr1) Then
```

You are going to get a lot more records when you make that change. This is because you loop through small.csv for each line of big.csv & add if it doesn't match. So each line of small.csv should get added multiple times.

If you change your loops around so that you loop through small.csv & check big.csv from that, then only add if it matches no line, you should get what you want.

```
For Each line1 In small
    Dim hasMatch As Boolean = False
    Dim smallFields As String() = line1.Split(";"c)

    'Moved to outer loop so it isn't done multiple times per line
    Dim pv2 As Date = smallFields(2)
    Dim p2 As Date = smallFields(3)
    Dim st2 As String = smallFields(16)

    Dim pvm2 = pv2.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")
    Dim pvm4 = p2.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")
    Dim substr2 As String = st2.Substring(st2.Length - 4, 4)

    For Each line2 In big
        Dim bigFields As String() = line2.Split(";"c)

        Dim pv1 As Date = bigFields(7)
        Dim p1 As Date = bigFields(8)
        Dim st1 As String = bigFields(3)

        Dim pvm1 = pv1.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")
        Dim pvm3 = p1.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")
        Dim substr1 As String = st1.Substring(st1.Length - 4, 4)

        If pvm2 = pvm1 AndAlso pvm3 = pvm4 AndAlso substr2 = substr1 Then
            'Event is in big.csv

            hasMatch = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not hasMatch Then
        smallFields(14) = substr2.ToString()
        sb.AppendLine(String.Join(";", smallFields))
    Else
        Label1.Text = "Ei löyty"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you @ItsPete for your help and time! It is exactly what I need.